# ORDER BY with CASE WHEN in row number

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a data as shown below

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------+
| user_id | purchase_bucket | Frequency |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+
|     123 | 8               |         2 |
|     321 | unclassified    |         1 |
|     124 | 4               |         3 |
|     124 | unclassified    |         1 |
|     125 | unclassified    |         3 |
|     125 | 4               |         3 |
|     125 | 2               |         1 |
|     126 | 4               |         8 |
|     126 | 2               |         8 |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+
```

It gives information about which purchase bucket an user is classified and that too how many times.

So user `123` is classified in `purchase_bucket` 8 twice. (`Frequency` = 2).

User `321` is in `unclassified` `purchase_bucket` for 1 time (`Frequency` = 1).

The problem is when the `Frequency` for a user has more than 1 `purchase_bucket` and both of them have same frequency

For example: User `125` has same `Frequency` for `unclassified` and `4`, both of them have `3` as frequency.

My desired result is as follows

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------+
| user_id | purchase bucket | Frequency |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+
|     123 | 8               |         2 |
|     321 | unclassified    |         1 |
|     124 | 4               |         3 |
|     125 | 4               |         3 |
|     126 | 4               |         8 |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+
```

So for user 123, 321 and 124 there is no issue. But for user 125 I would want `4` instead of `unclassified` in `purchase_bucket`.

For user `126` I dont care whether `4` or `2` comes in purchase bucket.

In a nutshell I dont want `unclassified` when there is some number with same `Frequency` in purchase bucket for a particular user.

I tried `row_number()` to eliminate the duplicates but was not able to get the desired results.

My query and result

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT *,
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY Frequency DESC) as Rn
FROM table1 ) T
WHERE T.Rn = 1

+---------+-----------------+-----------+----+
| user_id | purchase bucket | Frequency | Rn |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+----+
|     123 | 8               |         2 |  1 |
|     124 | 4               |         3 |  1 |
|     125 | unclassified    |         3 |  1 |
|     126 | 4               |         8 |  1 |
|     321 | unclassified    |         1 |  1 |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+----+
```

Sample [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vdEL5d7RFo6tmjiPackv4T/0)

Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: I dont want `unclassified`. Getting `unclassified` is the main problem for 125 when there is some other value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in unclassified to your ordering.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id 
                       ORDER BY CASE WHEN [purchase bucket] <> 'unclassified' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, 
                                Frequency DESC) as Rn
  FROM table1 
) T
WHERE T.Rn = 1
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error when I run the above query in [fiddle]  (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vdEL5d7RFo6tmjiPackv4T/0)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, my bad, sorry for it .

Comment: Can you explain what is happening in `ORDER BY` I am not able to get it with `CASE WHEN`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you question @Rookie_123 -- this case statement add 0 or 1 depending on if unclassified then uses that to order so all unclassified come last in the order.

Comment: @Hogan Okay, then after keeping unclassified last the other one's are sorted according to descending frequency ?

Comment: Thanks @Hogan Really appreciate your help